# Как войти в админку?

Tags: .htaccess, php, хостинг

Добрый вечер. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема...Решил сделать интернет магазин-выбрал движок simpla. Все работало на ура, но потом пришлось переехать на другой хостинг. Заново поставил движок и опля-при входе в админку выдает 404...Все работает кроме админки. Права на файлы 644, а на папках 755. При удалении .htaccess и .passwd все работает (ну то есть 404 уже не выдает) В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос:

> При удалении .htaccess и .passwd все работает (ну то есть 404 уже не выдает)

Копайте в этом направлении

Comment: Если бы знал как копать и где....наверное не спрашивал

Comment: Читайте доку к своему движку, вэб-серверу - гугл вам в помощь

Comment: еще читайте логи апача и смотрите откуда он пытается файлы брать